# Django Cannot load a template in the template path of INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using python 3.5.2 and django 1.11.6. My OS is win10. I cannot load my template in the installed_app path.

I've created a file at "polls/template/polls/index.html". I've also add the app, polls, into INSTALLED_APPS and set APP_DIRS in TEMPLATES to True. I cannot figure out why django won't load the template in the INSTALLED_APPS template folder as the tutorial told me.

I used the following code snippet to load the template in my view.

```
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = {
        'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

I got this TemplateDoesNotExist.
I'm wondering that why django doesn't search the path, "polls/template".
The paths searched by django are as following.

- django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\polls\index.html (Source does not exist)
- django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\polls\index.html (Source does not exist)

My INSTALLED_APPS is as following.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

My TEMPLATES setting is as following.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template directory is wrong. It should be `polls/templates/polls/index.html` - **templates** instead of **template**. From the tutorial:

> First, create a directory called **templates** in your polls directory. Django will look for templates in there.
>
> Within the templates directory you have just created, create another directory called polls, and within that create a file called index.html. In other words, your template should be at **polls/templates/polls/index.html**.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is, you can set template path in TEMPLATES in DIRS in settings.py.

```
'DIRS': [str(ROOT_DIR.path('polls/templates/polls/')),],
```

and set the ROOT_DIR which is root directory of your project, you can use environ to set root directory as:

```
ROOT_DIR = environ.Path(__file__) - 2
```

As this is complex compare to direct add `polls/templates/polls/index.html` but this will be helpful in general case. When project is going in high phase than it is important to convert that in general way.